# add to array a database column

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to retrieve strings from a database and log it into a listbox in visual studio here is my current code but for some reason it returns the column names instead shoud i use dr.getvalues() or something if yes how to use it?...

```
 cn.Open();
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Code, Name, Price, Quantity FROM dbo.[Table]";
 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 var colna = new List<string>();
 var colpr = new List<string>();

 for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
 {
      dr.Read();
      colna.Add(dr.GetName());
      colpr.Add(dr.GetName(i));
 }

 string[] sna = colna.ToArray();
 string[] spr = colpr.ToArray();

 listBox2.Items.AddRange(sna);
 listBox3.Items.AddRange(spr);


 dr.Close();
 cn.Close();
```

New Problem it only reads for 4 rows i tried turning tableDataGridView.RowCount into a variable no luck I tried replacing dr.fieldcount with tableDataGridView.RowCount still nothing if I try any of these above I get the error Invalid attempt to read when no data is present

if it serves anything this is how i filled up my database

```
try
{
    cn.Open();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [Table](Code, Name, Price, Quantity)VALUES('" + codeTextBox.Text + "','" + nameTextBox.Text + "','" + priceTextBox.Text + "','" + quantityTextBox.Text + "')";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cn.Close();
    string col1 = codeTextBox.Text;
    string col2 = nameTextBox.Text;
    string col3 = priceTextBox.Text;
    string col4 = quantityTextBox.Text;
    string[] row = { col1, col2, col3, col4 };
    tableDataGridView.Rows.Add(row);
}
catch (Exception bs)
{

}
```

this is on a different form

Comment: instead of  colna.Add(dr.GetName()); you can write colna.add(dr["Name"]);

Comment: I'm getting an error cannot convert object to string...

Comment: need explicit cast to string to avoid error using .toString() or convert.toString(val)

Comment: I tried that it dosent work

Comment: try this dr.GetOrdinal("Name"); or dr("Name"); and set to your list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you should be able to get the value of the field by changing

```
olpr.Add(dr.GetName(i));
```

to

```
olpr.Add(dr[i].ToString());



 cn.Open();
 cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Code, Name, Price, Quantity FROM dbo.[Table]";
 SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

 var colna = new List<string>();
 var colpr = new List<string>();

 dr.Read(); // this will only read one row
 for (int i = 0; i < dr.FieldCount; i++)
 {
      colna.Add(dr.GetName());
      colpr.Add(dr[i].ToString());
 }

 string[] sna = colna.ToArray();
 string[] spr = colpr.ToArray();

 listBox2.Items.AddRange(sna);
 listBox3.Items.AddRange(spr);
```

Comment: I'm getting cannot convert object to string

Comment: You might have to add ToString() if your fields are not of string type

Comment: Tried it it just prints string[] into the 2 listboxes nothing more noting less

Comment: darn it how could i miss that thanks now the problem is it only reads for 4 rows when i need it to read for like 200 rows

Comment: FYI, it reads 4 columns from one row... anyway, you may use a while (dr.Read()) { }, you will be able to read all the rows from the table

Answer (score 0):

Since return type of  SqlDataReader is an object. So you have to cast values to your desired type. Casting can be done in many different ways in C# as shown below:

```
SqlDataReader dr= command.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.HasRows)
        {

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                colna.Add(dr.GetString(1)) // name as string
                colpr.Add(dr.GetInt32(2)) // price is integer
                colpr.Add(Convert.ToDecimal(dr(2)))// if decimal
                colpr.Add((float)(dr(2))// if Float
                OR
                colna.Add(dr["Name"].ToString()); 
                colpr.Add((float)dr["Price"]);
                .... 
            }
            reader.NextResult();
        }
```